# Unable to download language data of tesseract

Tags: android, tesseract

The site http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz is not working and is not downloading the data. Is there any site where I can download the same data in the app. The error is "Cant download language data.Please enable network access and restart the app". My manifest file has permission for internet

Comment: If you are looking for samples try this .https://github.com/digitalbuddha/Android-OCR .Just download and run.

Comment: Sending request to http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz. Didn't get HTTP_OK response. This is the error I get

Comment: Then download the tessdata from here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr its on google sample projects. Or direct zip link tesseract-master https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/master.zip

Comment: I am new to this. I tried searching but couldn't find the exact file. I need the exact location.

Comment: This is exact location  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/master.zip

Comment: Do I need to put all the files in the tessdata folder??